# Integrating Apache Tomcat web server with Microsoft Visual Studio .net framework

Tags: java, c#, oracle, apache, tomcat

I am currently part of a team working on developing a Telemetry monitoring application. Since I am an Oracle Associate, I have been tasked with setting up an Oracle database at the back end and integrating it with an Apache-Tomcat Webserver that will display a log of all entries/transactions being conducted in the Oracle Database. The software application will be used to retrieve  and display all data (logs/entries etc) from the Data Engine (the Apache Tomcat webservice)

The problem is that our programming team intends to develop the software application in C# on Microsoft Visual studio which is confusing to me because while going through on-line documentation regarding integration of Apache-Tomcat web server with oracle database, I have come to understand that the Apache-Tomcat web service only works with Java applications and Java supported IDEs like eclipse (the documentation mostly details integration with reference to Java Servlets and JSPs)

Does that mean that I should:

A) request the programming team to change from Microsoft .net framework and Visual Studio to Java and Eclipse IDE so that there are no compatibility issues with Apache-Tomcat webserver

B) work with an alternate web server which is compatible with Microsoft Visual Studio, C# and the .net environment

C) Is there some kind of work around that will allow application development to proceed in C# and .net framework while still allowing us to use Apache Tomcat web servers?

Answer (score 1):

Apache Tomcat is a Java application server for deploying Java Servlet-based web applications. I'm sure there is a way to get .NET applications to run from it, but since you are starting from scratch, I would avoid doing that. Either switch application servers or switch implementation technologies.

Or, perhaps I am misunderstanding your architecture. Are you intending to build a Java-based service that runs on Apache Tomcat, and a separate standalone application that contacts this service to fetch its information? If so, there's no problem, as long as the protocol for communicating between the two applications is well-defined (e.g. REST, XML-over-HTTP, SOAP, etc.).

It would be perfectly reasonable to write a Java-based service and then connect to it from any number of applications written using any combinations of technologies.

But don't try to deploy a .NET-based web application on Tomcat. You'll just be wasting a huge amount of time for no good reason.